# Phonegap svg clickable and link to other html in same folder

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to build my first app in android with html js and phonegap. I have two problems and i think they are about the same.

1)
My app has a svg image that is clickable (thanks inkscape!), and some other html pages, in the same folder of index.html (anyway, I've other folders with img, js and css files). I want that when I click on the clickable svg I can load another html page of the folder. I mean, I have

```
 <object id="image" data="img/pianta.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

which is my svg included in index.html, and into pianta.svg I have

```
 <a
       id="a3079"
       xlink:href="/swipepages.html"
       target="_top"
       xlink:title="cinque"><g
         enable-background="new    "
         opacity="0.5216"
         id="Rectangle_4_1_">
        <g
       id="Rectangle_4">
            <g
       id="g3037">
                <polygon
       id="polygon3039"
       points="666.8,312 562.1,311.1 561.8,389.3 679.4,386.8    "
       fill="#FFFF00"
       clip-rule="evenodd"
       fill-rule="evenodd" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </g></a>
```

where swipepages.html is another file html in the same folder of index.html, and i want it to be load swipepages.html when I click on that point.

2)
I've a sidebar which has some buttons and I want to load another html page when I click on one of that.

On my pc and browser everything looks working fine, but when I build the app with phongeap and I try it I've the error "error file not found". How can i solve this? thanks!

Comment: Maybe replacing the slash in the url by an hashtag fix your problem like this: #swipepages.html

Comment: thanks! I've not seen your answer before, but i solved (look at my answer, it works) :-)

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has the same problem, I found a solution on my own (but still looking through stackoverflow's posts). I included this script in my svg:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //check if close element exists. If yes, execute the function
        if($('.close').length() > 0) load_thankyou();
    });

    function load_thankyou()
    {
        alert('hii');
        var delay = 1000; //Your delay in milliseconds
        var URL = 'swipepages.html';
        setTimeout(function()
                    { 
                      window.location = URL; 
                    }, delay);
    }

  ]]></script></svg>
```

And modified the a tag where I put the link from this:

```
<a
   id="a3063"
   xlink:href="MYURL"
   target="_top"
   xlink:title="title">
```

to this:

```
<a class="close" id="a3079" xlink:href="NAMEOFTHEPAGEIWANT" target="_top" xlink:title="title">
```

And then I discovered that is better putting every file (images, html files..) in the same folder (www) in phonegap: probably is not the right solution, but it works fine.